# Error with PyQtDeploy

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm using PyQt 5.3.1 and I'm deploying with pyqtdeploy 0.4 and when i want to build a project i obtain this error message:

```
Generating code...
Cleaning E:\ProgramasPython3\PythonQT\QTCalculator\build.
Freezing C:\Users\Tobal\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap_py3.py
Freezing E:\ProgramasPython3\PythonQT\QTCalculator\qtcalculator.py
Freezing E:/ProgramasPython3/PythonQT\QTCalculator\__init__.py
Freezing E:/ProgramasPython3/PythonQT\QTCalculator\calculator_ui.py
Freezing E:/ProgramasPython3/PythonQT\QTCalculator\img_rc.py
Freezing E:/ProgramasPython3/PythonQT\QTCalculator\qtcalculator.py
Freezing C:\Python34\libs\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py
Unable to freeze C:\Python34\libs\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tobal\AppData\Local\Temp\freeze.py", line 103, in <module>
    freeze_as_data(py_file, options.as_data)
  File "C:\Users\Tobal\AppData\Local\Temp\freeze.py", line 36, in freeze_as_data
    code = _get_marshalled_code(py_filename)
  File "C:\Users\Tobal\AppData\Local\Temp\freeze.py", line 71, in _get_marshalled_code
    source_file = open(py_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34\\libs\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\__init__.py'
```

I think this is a bug. someone does know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you build PyQt5 statically?  The host and target Python are two different things, and often in different directories.  The target Python has PyQt module built statically, the host Python must also have PyQt5 installed (because pyqtdeploy uses Qt for its GUI) but its usually a dynamic library in the host Python.

Answer (score 0):

In the pyqtdeploy GUI on "Locations" tab, make sure that "Standard library directory" is correct.